# Table separation and subsetting

Tags: r, string, subset

I hope you can help me with this problem I have the following data frame obtained form StarkLab lines of enhancer construction reporters.

```
Lines <- data.frame(VTID = c("VT0006", "VT0007", "VT0112") , 
                    Chr = c("chr2L", "chr3R", "chr3L"), 
                    pattern = c("ubitquitous;4", "procephalic_ectoderm_AISN;4|posterior;3", "dorsal ectoderm anlage; 4|posterior_endoderm_AISN;2|posterior_endoderm_AISN;2" )
```

I want to obtain from the column `pattern` just the string that has the higher value after `;`, I don't know how to do it given some strings are also divided by `|` some by two `|` other by 3 `|`. If you have a best idea of how to classify all the strings I'm open to suggestions. How would you solve it in R?

Comment: perhaps `Lines$values <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(Lines$pattern), '\\|'), function(x){as.numeric(sub('^.*;\\s*', '', x))})`, though how you want the result to be structured is unclear; you should specify.

Comment: Thank you thats helpfull, the final result i want its a column with the string that has the highest value.

Comment: A better way to approach this would be to tidy your data, e.g. `library(tidyr); Lines %>% separate_rows(pattern, sep = '\\|') %>% separate(pattern, c('key', 'value'), sep = ';', convert = TRUE)` after which subsetting and aggregation are simple.

Comment: wow yes this one is the best way thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can pull out the information directly with regex, a more robust technique is to tidy the data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Lines <- data.frame(VTID = c("VT0006", "VT0007", "VT0112") , 
                    Chr = c("chr2L", "chr3R", "chr3L"), 
                    pattern = c("ubitquitous;4", "procephalic_ectoderm_AISN;4|posterior;3", "dorsal ectoderm anlage; 4|posterior_endoderm_AISN;2|posterior_endoderm_AISN;2" ),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_lines <- Lines %>% 
    separate_rows(pattern, sep = '\\|') %>% 
    separate(pattern, c('key', 'value'), sep = ';', convert = TRUE)

df_lines
#>     VTID   Chr                       key value
#> 1 VT0006 chr2L               ubitquitous     4
#> 2 VT0007 chr3R procephalic_ectoderm_AISN     4
#> 3 VT0007 chr3R                 posterior     3
#> 4 VT0112 chr3L    dorsal ectoderm anlage     4
#> 5 VT0112 chr3L   posterior_endoderm_AISN     2
#> 6 VT0112 chr3L   posterior_endoderm_AISN     2
```

after which subsetting or aggregating is trivial:

```r
df_lines %>% group_by(VTID, Chr) %>% top_n(1, value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   VTID, Chr [3]
#>   VTID   Chr   key                       value
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>                     <int>
#> 1 VT0006 chr2L ubitquitous                   4
#> 2 VT0007 chr3R procephalic_ectoderm_AISN     4
#> 3 VT0112 chr3L dorsal ectoderm anlage        4
```

If you don't want to split the data into multiple lines, you can insert a list column of data frames, instead. Working with them will be a little more work, but sometimes the idiom makes sense. In base R,

```r
Lines$data <- lapply(strsplit(Lines$pattern, '\\|'), function(x){
    read.csv2(text = paste(x, collapse = '\n'), 
              header = FALSE, col.names = c('key', 'value'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})

str(Lines)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ VTID   : chr  "VT0006" "VT0007" "VT0112"
#>  $ Chr    : chr  "chr2L" "chr3R" "chr3L"
#>  $ pattern: chr  "ubitquitous;4" "procephalic_ectoderm_AISN;4|posterior;3" "dorsal ectoderm anlage; 4|posterior_endoderm_AISN;2|posterior_endoderm_AISN;2"
#>  $ data   :List of 3
#>   ..$ :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ key  : chr "ubitquitous"
#>   .. ..$ value: int 4
#>   ..$ :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ key  : chr  "procephalic_ectoderm_AISN" "posterior"
#>   .. ..$ value: int  4 3
#>   ..$ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ key  : chr  "dorsal ectoderm anlage" "posterior_endoderm_AISN" "posterior_endoderm_AISN"
#>   .. ..$ value: int  4 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regmatches` to capture the strings

```
 sapply(regmatches(Lines$pattern,gregexpr(".*?\\d",Lines$pattern)),function(x)x[which.max(sub("\\D*","",x))])
[1] "ubitquitous;4"               "procephalic_ectoderm_AISN;4" "dorsal ectoderm anlage; 4"
```

You can also use the `strsplit` function as given in the comment

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(Lines$pattern),"\\|"),function(x)x[which.max(sub("\\D*","",x))])
[1] "ubitquitous;4"               "procephalic_ectoderm_AISN;4" "dorsal ectoderm anlage; 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Lines$pattern <- as.character(Lines$pattern)
Lines$values <- gsub("\\D*", ",", Lines$pattern)

get_highest <- function(x) {
  split <- strsplit(x, ",")
  split <- unlist(lapply(split, function(s) max(as.numeric(s[s != ""]))))
  return(split)
}

Lines$max <- get_highest(Lines$values)
Lines$regex <-paste0("(",paste0(".*", Lines$max),").*")
Lines$final <- apply(Lines, 1, function(x) gsub(x[6], "\\1", x[3]))

Lines$final 
# "ubitquitous;4"               "procephalic_ectoderm_AISN;4" "dorsal ectoderm anlage; 4"
```